# R: Recode a single factor of a variable using multiple conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a factor variable with 4 levels:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- sample(1:4,20,replace=TRUE)
df <- factor(d,labels=c("A","B","C","D"))
```

I want to distribute "C" between "B" and "D" conditional on the values of another variable:

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df)[names(df)=="df"] <- "var1"
df$var2 <- rnorm(20,5,2)
```

I thought I could subset "C" while `ifelse` recodes based on some criteria; say

```
df$var1[df$var1=="C"] <- ifelse(df$var1=="C" & df$var2 < 4, "B", "D")
```

But R doesn't like it (probably for a good reason) and allocates all Cs to "D". I suspect the second conditional does not work as intended. It is also possible that there is a more efficient solution even if this works. Thoughts?

Comment: If I don't subset at the beginning `df$var1=="C"` , then virtually everything is allocated to "D"

Comment: "But R doesn't like it" isn't a great description, the actual warning message is: 

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$var1 == "C", value = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @EricWatt Yes, you are right - should have supplied the error in the initial post - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
sub.df <- df[df$var1=="C",] # subset you are concerned
sub.df$var1 <- ifelse(sub.df$var2 < 4, "B", "D") # modify
df[df$var1=="C",] <- sub.df # update the subset
```

Answer (score 3):

I think , you need

```
df$var1[df$var1 == "C"] <- ifelse(df[df$var1 == "C", "var2"] < 4, "B", "D")
```

This would still keep the level `C` in it.

```
df$var1
#[1] B B B D A D D D D A A A D B D B D D B D
#Levels: A B C D
```

You can drop the unused levels using `droplevels`

```
df$var1 <- droplevels(df$var1)

df$var1
#[1] B B B D A D D D D A A A D B D B D D B D
#Levels: A B D
```

Or just apply `factor` again

```
df$var1 <- factor(df$var1)
```

Comment: Hi, the first chunk gives error for me, but thanks for the droplevels and re-factoring tips

Comment: Ehm, I ran it again and it works. Maybe I inadvertently messed it up the first time, sorry!